# Depicting a function which looks like a geometric sequence

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I am to graph the following function:
$f(x) = 1 + \frac{3x}{x^2 - 10} + (\frac{3x}{x^2 - 10})^2 + \dots  $
I tried to use the formula for the sum of a geometric sequence, where: 
$a_0 = 1; m = \frac{3x}{x^2 - 10} $
And so the formula for the sum:
$S = a_0\frac{1}{1 - m}$, which gives me
$S = \frac{x^2 - 10}{x^2 - 3x - 10}$, but this form is really hard to plot.
Can I do anything to simplify the formula, and so to graph it easier?

Comment: For this to work you need to impose that $\left|\frac{3x}{x^2-10}\right|<1$. This will reduce the domain of $f$. Otherwise the formula for the sum is not correct!

Comment: Thank you for this hint. 
I also thought about using partial fractions, would it do anythnig good here?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use an online plotter? By the way, you may write the denominator as $(x-5)(x+2)$, so yes perhaps partial fractions can do something. Find first the values of $x$ so that $m<1$!